# How to tell if gpu is overheating without sensor

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, cooling, temperature

I just took apart my dell xps m1210 to re-apply thermal paste. I used thermal PASTE instead of a thermal PAD on the gpu, but I think it should work fine.

Even so, I worry about weather the gpu is getting to hot or not. The computer does not have a temperature monitor built into the graphics card (unless that happens to be "temp 1" which is always very close to the cpu temperature.

So my question is: is there any way to tell whether my graphics card is too hot without a sensor built in?

Thanks

EDIT:

This computer was originally running windows 7. It kept restarting and shutting down, sometimes even before the OS. it would do this very quickly. I took apart the computer and noticed the thermal paste was all dried out on the cpu. I replaced that, and replaced the thermal pad on the gpu with thermal paste (the paste was very glob-like and non-conductive).

I put the computer back togeather and the shut down issues appear to be fixed and cpu runs 50 degrees below tj maxx. At this point I installed Ubuntu. My only concern is about the gpu since it might not trigger a shutdown if it gets to hot.

Comment: How are you reading the temps now?

Comment: I used to just tell by waiting until things started melting.

Comment: But, seriously, what application are use using to tell temperatures?

Comment: Paste is usually a poor replacement for pads because pads are expected to fill a gap and paste expects components to be flush.

Comment: You could wait for it to overheat and die, or until the PC shuts down, or you get performance issues, but generally, there is a reason why we have and should use sensors!

Comment: I am running ubuntu right now, and using "Psensor" It is a fresh install. Just added more information about the backstory in the original post